# Unable to Display Text in Hindi Language in PHP Website

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display text in Hindi Language in my website but it is giving me error. In return the value is showing as "????"

How do I display the text in Hindi or other language.

I have the META tags as well in place.

Comment: Why you have java tag?

Comment: Have you set the encoding in html document?

Comment: use UTF-8 encoding in your html

Comment: are you retrieving hindi text from database? please specify

Comment: you will have to use utf-8 encoding in your html page. If you are reading content from mysql db, then db fields should also be set to handle utf-8.

Comment: No i am not pulling the text from any db... Need to add the Marahi/Hindi text option on header for Language change option... Have used UTF-8 tag bu still no luck ... I have been trying this since 2 hours.